# Read numbers from multiple files and sum

Tags: powershell

I have a logfile C:\temp\data.log
It contains the following data:

```
totalSize = 222,6GB

totalSize = 4,2GB

totalSize = 56,2GB
```

My goal is to extract the numbers from the file and sum them up including the number after the comma. So far it works if I don't regex the number included with value after comma, and only use the number in front of the comma. The other problem I have is if the file only contains one row like below example, if it only contains one line it splits up the number 222 into three file containing the number 2 in three files. If the above logfile contains 2 lines or more it works and sums up as it should, as long I don't use value with comma.

```
totalSize                      = 222,6GB
```

Here is a bit of the code for the regex to add to end of existing variable `$regex` included with comma is:

```
[,](\d{1,})
```

I haven't included the above regex, as it does not sum up properly then.

The whole script is below:

```
#Create path variable to store contents grabbed from $log_file
$extracted_strings = "C:\temp\amount.txt"
#Create path variable to read from original file
$log_file = "C:\temp\data.log"
#Read data from file $log_file
Get-Content -Path $log_file | Select-String "(totalSize = )" | out-file $extracted_strings
#Create path variable to write only numbers to file $output_numbers
$output_numbers = "C:\temp\amountresult.log"
#Create path variable to write to file jobblog1
$joblog1_file = "C:\temp\joblog1.txt"
#Create path variable to write to file jobblog2
$joblog2_file = "C:\temp\joblog2.txt"
#Create path variable to write to file jobblog3
$joblog3_file = "C:\temp\joblog3.txt"
#Create path variable to write to file jobblog4
$joblog4_file = "C:\temp\joblog4.txt"
#Create path variable to write to file jobblog5
$joblog5_file = "C:\temp\joblog5.txt"
#Create pattern variable to read with select string
$regex = "[= ](\d{1,})"
select-string -Path $extracted_strings -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }  > $output_numbers
(Get-Content -Path $output_numbers)[0..0] -replace '\s' > $joblog1_file
(Get-Content -Path $output_numbers)[1..1] -replace '\s' > $joblog2_file
(Get-Content -Path $output_numbers)[2..2] -replace '\s' > $joblog3_file
(Get-Content -Path $output_numbers)[3..3] -replace '\s' > $joblog4_file
(Get-Content -Path $output_numbers)[4..4] -replace '\s' > $joblog5_file
$jobdata0 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog1_file)
$jobdata1 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog2_file)
$jobdata2 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog3_file)
$jobdata3 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog4_file)
$jobdata4 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog5_file)
$result = $jobdata0  + $jobdata1 + $jobdata2 + $jobdata3 + $jobdata4
$result
```

So my questions is:

1. How can I get this to work if the file C:\temp\data.log only contains one string without dividing that single number into multiple files. It should also work if it contains multiple strings, as it is now it works with multiple strings.
2. And how can I include the comma values in the calculation?

The result I get if I run this script should be 282, maybe its even possible to shorten the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where `$log_file` has contents like the example above.

```
Get-Content $log_file | Where-Object{$_ -match "\d+(,\d+)?"} | 
    ForEach-Object{[double]($matches[0] -replace ",",".")} | 
    Measure-Object -Sum | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty sum
```

Match all of the lines that have numerical values with optional commas. I am assuming they could be optional as I do not know how whole numbers appear. Replace the comma with a period and cast as a double. Using measure object we sum up all the values and expand the result.

Not the only way to do it but it is simple enough to understand what is going on.

You can always wrap the above up in a loop so that you can use it for multiple files. `Get-ChildItem "C:temp\" -Filter "job*" | ForEach-Object`... etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Matt's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43345786/45375) shows a concise and effective solution.

As for **what you tried**:

As for why a line with  a *single* token such as `222,6` can result in *multiple* outputs in this command:

```
select-string -Path $extracted_strings -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | 
  % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }  > $output_numbers
```

Your regex, `[= ](\d{1,})`, does *not* explain the symptom, but just `\d{1,}` would, because that would capture `222` and `6` *separately*, due to `-AllMatches`.

`[= ](\d{1,})` probably doesn't do what you want, because `[= ]` matches a *single* character that can be *either* a `=` *or* a space; with your sample input, this would only ever match the space before the numbers.
To match characters *in sequence*, simply place them next to each other: `= (\d{1,})`

Also note that even though you're enclosing `\d{1,}` in `(...)` to create  a capture group, your later code doesn't actually use what that capture group matched; use `(...)` only if you need it for precedence (in which case you can even opt out of subexpression capturing with `(?:...)`) or if you do have a need to access what the subexpression matched.

That said, you *could* actually utilize a capture group here (an alternative would be to use a look-behind assertion), which allows you to both match the leading `=<space>` for robustness and extract only the numeric token of interest (saving you the need to trim whitespace later).
If we simplify `\d{1,}` to `\d+` and append `,\d+` to also match the number after the comma, we get:

```
= (\d+,\d+)
```

The `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]` instances returned by `Select-String` then allow us to access what the capture group captured, via the `.Groups` property (the following simplified example also works with multiple input lines):

```
> 'totalSize = 222,6GB' | Select-String '= (\d+,\d+)' | % { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
222,6
```

---

On a side note: **your code contains a lot of repetition** that could be eliminated with arrays and pipelines; for instance:

```
$joblog1_file = "C:\temp\joblog1.txt"
$joblog2_file = "C:\temp\joblog2.txt"
$joblog3_file = "C:\temp\joblog3.txt"
$joblog4_file = "C:\temp\joblog4.txt"
$joblog5_file = "C:\temp\joblog5.txt"
```

could be replaced with (create an *array* of filenames, using a pipeline):

```
$joblog_files = 1..5 | % { "C:\temp\joblog$_.txt" }
```

and

```
$jobdata0 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog1_file)
$jobdata1 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog2_file)
$jobdata2 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog3_file)
$jobdata3 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog4_file)
$jobdata4 = (Get-Content -Path $joblog5_file)
$result = $jobdata0  + $jobdata1 + $jobdata2 + $jobdata3 + $jobdata4
```

could then be replaced with (pass the *array* of filenames to `Get-Content`):

```
$result = Get-Content $joblog_files
```

Comment: I didn't have the time to go through his code as I knew this would be the result. I'm glad someone took the time.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. My hope is that between our two answers we now have both groups of future readers covered: those looking for an elegant solution, and those looking for an explanation.

Comment: Yeah. I normally enjoy this type of thing on SO and CR but I am apparently being paid to do other things right now.

Comment: Thankyou guys for the explanations, it will help me to do better and simplified powershellscripts.